# Basic calculation with pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dfA,

```
1   2   5
2   3   6
3   3   8
```

and dfB,

```
2
4
1
```

How to multiply first element in B with all elements in first column from A, second element from B with all elements in second column from A and so on.
So result should look like this:

```
2 8  5
4 12 6
6 12 8
```

I tried this, and at the end to store everything in df C2 but something does not work properly. Any hint or help more than welcome.

```
empty_C = []
for x in range(3):
    C = A.iloc[:,x] * B.iloc[x,:]
    empty_C.append(C)
    C2 = np.stack(empty_C)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be DataFrames? Numpy was built for this operation

Comment: What are the column and row indices? If they're not important, you should probably be using NumPy instead.

Comment: BTW, check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Comment: The columns and row indices are not important ... hmm numpy will try. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you need to pivot B so its elements correspond to columns.

Comment: Probably you are right, but I do not understand what you trying to say :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have these 2 dataframes:

```
df1:

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     2     5
1     2     3     6
2     3     3     8

df2:

   colB
0     2
1     4
2     1
```

Then you can do (note that df2 is transposed and only the numpy array is used (without pandas indices)):

```py
print(df1 * df2.T.values)
```

Prints:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     2     8     5
1     4    12     6
2     6    12     8
```